# Why do we need to swap grid_model and next_grid_model?

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

This is a part of code of John Conway's GAME OF LIFE

```
import random

height = 100

width = 100

def randomize(grid, width, height):

   for i in range(0, height):

       for j in range(0, width):

           grid[i][j] = random.randint(0,1)

grid_model = [0] * height

next_grid_model = [0] * height

for i in range(height):

   grid_model[i] = [0] * width

   next_grid_model[i] = [1] * width

def next_gen():

   global grid_model, next_grid_model

   for i in range(0, height):

       for j in range(0, width):

           cell = 0

           count = count_neighbors(grid_model, i, j)

           if grid_model[i][j] == 0:

               if count == 3:

                   cell = 1 

           elif grid_model[i][j] == 1:

               if count == 2 or count == 3:

                   cell = 1

           next_grid_model[i][j] = cell

   temp = grid_model

   grid_model = next_grid_model

   next_grid_model = temp

def count_neighbors(grid, row, col):

   count = 0

   if row-1 >= 0:

        count = count + grid[row-1][col]

   if (row-1 >= 0) and (col-1 >= 0):

       count = count + grid[row-1][col-1]

   if (row-1 >= 0) and (col+1 < width):

       count = count + grid[row-1][col+1]

   if col-1 >= 0:

       count = count + grid[row][col-1]

   if col + 1 < width:

       count = count + grid[row][col+1]

   if row + 1 < height:

       count = count + grid[row+1][col]

   if (row + 1 < height) and (col-1 >= 0):

       count = count + grid[row+1][col-1]

   if (row + 1 < height) and (col+1 < width):

       count = count + grid[row+1][col+1]

   return count

glider_pattern = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],

                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],

                  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],

                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

glider_gun_pattern = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],

              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

def load_pattern(pattern, x_offset=0, y_offset=0):

    global grid_model

    for i in range(0, height):

        for j in range(0, width):

            grid_model[i][j] = 0

    j = y_offset

    for row in pattern:

        i = x_offset

        for value in row:

            grid_model[i][j] = value

            i = i + 1

        j = j + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    next_gen()



temp = grid_model

   grid_model = next_grid_model

   next_grid_model = temp
```

What I want to ask is why we need to swap grid_model and next_grid_model?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this small example

```
000
111
```

It should be followed by this grid

```
010
010
```

- upper corners are 0, and surrounded by two 1, so they remain 0
- lower corners are 1, and surrounded by one 1, so they become 0
- upper middle pixel is 0 and surrounded by three 1, so it becomes 1.
- lower middle pixel is 1 and surrounded by two 1, so it stays 1

Now, what would happen if you were using only one grid, that is compute this in situ:
You would start with grid

```
000
111
```

First pixel is 0, surround by two 1, so it stays 0, and grid stays

```
000
111
```

Second pixel is 0 surrounded by three 1, so it becomes 1. And grid becomes

```
010
111
```

Third pixel is 0, surrounded by three 1, so it becomes 1, and grid becomes

```
011
111
```

Fourth pixel (on 2nd line) is 1, surrounded by two 1, it stays 1.

```
011
111
```

Fifth pixel is 1, surrounded by four 1, it becomes 0

```
011
101
```

At last, sixth pixel is 1, surrounded by two 1, it stays 1

```
011
101
```

So, result is completely different from the expected result.
You get grid

```
011
101
```

Instead of grid

```
010
010
```

That is not directly the answer to your question. It is the answer to "why can't I just compute using a single grid, and why I need to compute a `next_grid` from a `current_grid`".

And my answer shows that you need to compute a new grid from a current grid.

Now, you have two options to do so.

- Either at each step you allocate and compute a new grid, that, once computed becomes the current grid, and the former current grid is simply forgotten. That force you to redo the `next_grid_model = [0] * height` and `for i in range(height):   next_grid_model[i] = [1] * width` each time. But it would work
- Or, you don't want to bother creating a brand new `next_grid_model` at each step. So you just reuse the `grid_model` variable, that still exists, and whose, after all, you don't need any more, since you intend to replace it by `next_grid_model`.

That is the reason for the swap:

- `next_grid_model` becomes `grid_model`, because, that is the game (I take you get that part. Again, from the first part of my answer, you probably understand why we need to compute a `next_grid_model` instead of updating `grid_model` directly. But then `next_grid_model`, as its name indicate, becomes the new `grid_model`.
- And we need to create a new 2d-array to be the new `next_grid_model`. And if we don't want to create it from scratch, one solution is to say that the old `grid_model` will host the future `next_grid_model`. Hence the swap.

Note that such a trick is more important in other languages than in python. In C, for example, to allocate both grid, we would have to call `malloc`.
And calling `malloc` to create a new grid at each stage, while calling `free` on the former grids is a little bit stupid (allocating exactly the same amount of memory we are freeing — without free, it is even worse, and a memory leak).  So it is quite classical in such case, to swap the "current" and "future" memories, instead of allocating a new one each time.

In python, if you were to just create a new `next_grid_model` each time, it would also work. Garbage collector would take care of all the former grids that you dropped, and everything would be fine. But even if it would work, that still would mean that you have to to the job of creating a new `next_grid_model` each time.

So a shorter answer could have been:
at each stage you need either to

```py
next_grid_model = [0] * height
for i in range(height):
   next_grid_model[i] = [1] * width
```

Or to

```py
    # Just a swap (I write it that way, because it is more compact, 
    # but it is the same thing as your 3 lines involving a temp variable)
    next_grid_model, grid_model = grid_model, next_grid_model
```

Both works. They are just two way to create a future `next_grid_model`. Swap is simply faster.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and careful answer!
temp = grid_model
   grid_model = next_grid_model
   next_grid_model = temp
      Could you simply explain the code above?  If I don't swap both of them,does it mean both of them would point to the same list?

Comment: If you just remove that code, then your grid will never change. `grid_model` will remain forever the 1st stage, that is the original grid. And `next_grid_model` will remain for ever the 2nd stage. And you will never compute the 3rd, 4th, ... stages. To compute the 3rd stage, you need to start from the 2nd stage.  So you need `grid_model` to be the 2nd stage, that you have computed in `next_grid_model`.